# How to install dependent libraries with CMake?

Tags: installation, cmake

I want to install all dependent libraries.

To do that I do

```
install(FILES "path/external.dll" DESTINATION lib)
```

However, I have already configured the path(and the lib) with `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "path/external.dll")
```

So, I think that I might not need again telling `install FILES`

I would be able to do this with `install TARGETS`, would not I?

However,

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

does not install dependent libraries.

How could I do that without repeating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake 3.21 added an argument to `install(TARGETS)` for this: `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES`. Try this:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(
    TARGETS my_target
    RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
        [DIRECTORIES ...]
)
```

Where `DIRECTORIES` marks the beginning of an optional list of search paths. Also note that including GNUInstallDirs sets up the default destinations correctly.

See the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets

Comment: Why do we have to give again DIRECTORIES, but not does it use automatically dependencies used when linking?

Comment: @MertMertce -- It internally uses `file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)`, which uses system tools to ask the compiled binary for the list of dependencies. On Linux and macOS, it will use the embedded RPATH information, but Windows has no corresponding concept. It might also be the case that the user has disabled CMake's RPATH handling with `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH`. So you should check `WIN32` and `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH` and add `DIRECTORIES "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:lib::lib>"` if either is set.

Comment: Also note that this will grab _everything_, including system libraries like `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s`. You can either filter this or manually install the dependencies you know you need via [`install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#imported-runtime-artifacts)

Comment: However, libraries that we add with ```target_link_libraries``` cannot be found directly with ```TARGET_FILE_DIR```, right? We have to create another target with ```add_library(MyLib ... IMPORTED)```

Comment: You should only ever use `target_link_libraries` with other targets to prevent environment variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from affecting your build. `TARGET_FILE_DIR` works with any library _target_, imported or not.

Comment: @AlexReinking Is there a way yet to get JUST the transitive build dependencies (e.g., shared libraries) that your primary target depends on and caused to be built?   This is such a simple problem, and CMake fails so hard at solving it.

Comment: @alexchandel - not in general, no. The `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS>` generator expression often suffices.